# formatting tables with CSS?

Tags: css, html, tablerow, tablecell

I want to create a table using CSS only (no   tags). My goal is to create a two-row table, the first row having two cells, the second row having one cell. The cell content stacks vertically. Thx for your help.

```css
article {
  display: table;
  width: 440px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

section {
  display: table-row;
}

article.section img {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 130px; 
}

article.section p {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
 <article>   <!-- table -->
   <section> <!-- table row 1 -->
  <img src="images/People/napoleon.jpg" /> <!-- row 1, cell 1 -->
  <img src="images/Symbols/fleurBlue.jpg" /> <!-- row 1, cell 2 -->   
   </section>
   
   <section> <!-- row 2 -->
     <p> This is Napoleon Bonaparte as 
    Emperor of France wearing his military 
  uniform. 
  </p> 
   </section>
</article>
```

[Refer this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1u2gvff9/)

Comment: I have answered to your question. But i am not clear about your need at ROWS! do you want this type of structure: row 1: cell 1, cell2                                           row 2 :cell 3

Answer (score 1):

Selectors are incorrect.

`article.section img` and `article.section p` should be `article section img` and `article section p`.

Comment: that's what i thought but the book i'm using uses the "article.section" format; i don't understand why when you could just use "article section"

Answer (score 1):

With response to your Jsfiddle i have made changes [on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1u2gvff9/)

You have putted unnecessary `.` in selectors. That's It.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following css

```
article.section img {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 130px; 
}

article.section p {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 130px;
}
```

`article.section` is a [Class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html), so it would apply to all `<article>` tags with `class="section"` attribute like below

```
<article class="section">   <!-- table -->
   <section> <!-- table row 1 -->
     <img src="images/People/napoleon.jpg" /> <!-- row 1, cell 1 -->
     <img src="images/Symbols/fleurBlue.jpg" /> <!-- row 1, cell 2 -->       
   </section>

   <section> <!-- row 2 -->
     <p> This is Napoleon Bonaparte as 
       Emperor of France wearing his military 
        uniform. 
     </p> 
   </section>
</article>
```

but you actually want to select all `<section>` tags that are contained by `<article>` tags, so what you need is [Descendant selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors). Change `article.section` to `article section` (replace the dot with a space) as below

```
article section img {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 130px; 
}

article section p {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 130px;
}
```

Comment: What does the period between selectors do anyway?

Comment: It's called descendant selectors. See here for more info: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#descendant-selectors, I also have updated my answer.